# How to construct angular_momentum_constraint without a model plant?

Tags: drake

Follow the [liitledog tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/examples/littledog.ipynb), I want to optimize a jump motion with the center of mass `com`, `comdot`, `comddot`, spatial momentum `H`, `Hdot`, contact force `f`, as the decision variables（remove the position and velocity `q` and `v`）.

I want to add a constrain that `Hdot = sum_i cross(p_WF_i-com, f_i)`, `p_WF` is the fix  contact point (four points). I tried follow the littledog with

---

```
def angular_momentum_constraint(vars, context_index):
    com, Hdot, contact_force = np.split(vars, [3, 6])
    contact_force = contact_force.reshape(3, 4, order='F')
    if isinstance(vars[0], AutoDiffXd):
        torque = np.zeros(3)
        for i in range(4):
            p_WF = plant.CalcPointsPositions(plant_context, foot_frame[i], [0,0,0], plant.world_frame())
            Jq_WF = plant.CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity(
                plant_context, JacobianWrtVariable.kQDot,
                foot_frame[i], [0, 0, 0], plant.world_frame(), plant.world_frame())
            ad_p_WF = initializeAutoDiffGivenGradientMatrix(p_WF, np.hstack((Jq_WF, np.zeros((3, 18)))))
            torque = torque     + np.cross(ad_p_WF.reshape(3) - com, contact_force[:,i])
    else:
        torque = np.zeros(3)
        for i in range(4):
            p_WF = plant.CalcPointsPositions(plant_context, foot_frame[i], [0,0,0], plant.world_frame())
            torque += np.cross(p_WF.reshape(3) - com, contact_force[:,i])
    return Hdot - torque
```

---

But the prog will always reach the iterations limit (1e6) adding this constrain.
My question is:

1. In the liitledog tutorial, why does the ad_p_WF need a Jacobian w.r.t QDot as  GradientMatrix when computing the contact wrench?
2. How to fill the GradientMatrix without using the  `plant.CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity` as there is no `q` and `v` in the mathematicalprogram?

Here is the source code [testjump.py](https://github.com/zisang/humanoid/blob/simplerigid/testJump.py), thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `q` and `v` are not your decision variables any more, you don't need to compute the Jacobian of p_WF. I would rewrite the code block

```py
Jq_WF = plant.CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity(
                plant_context, JacobianWrtVariable.kQDot,
                foot_frame[i], [0, 0, 0], plant.world_frame(), plant.world_frame())
ad_p_WF = initializeAutoDiffGivenGradientMatrix(p_WF, np.hstack((Jq_WF, np.zeros((3, 18)))))
torque = torque     + np.cross(ad_p_WF.reshape(3) - com, contact_force[:,i])
```

as

```py
torque = torque + np.cross(p_WF.reshape(3) - com, contact_force[:, i])
```

where p_WF is fixed point in the world frame. (So don't call `p_WF = plant.CalcPointsPositions(plant_context, foot_frame[i], [0,0,0], plant.world_frame())` within that function `angular_momentum_constraint`, as the value of p_WF is doesn't depend on the input to that function.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. May I ask why this lead to a `SNOPTA INFO  43 -- cannot satisfy the general constraints`.  I tried `p_WF = plant.CalcPointsPositions(plant_context, foot_frame[i], [0,0,0], plant.world_frame()) and ad_p_WF = initializeAutoDiff(p_WF) `

Comment: You do not need to call `initializeAutoDiff(p_WF)`. `ad_p_WF = initializeAutoDiff(p_WF)` will set the gradient of `ad_p_WF` to be identity matrix, namely it wants to take the derivative w.r.t p_WF. But in your case p_WF is fixed, and you don't want to take its derivative. You should call `ad_p_WF = np.array([AutoDiffXd(p_WF[i]) for i in range(3)])`, which set the deriative of `ad_p_WF` to empty.